# Conic involving circle question.

Tags: conic-sections

The question is:
If the curves $ax^2+4xy+2y^2+x+y+5=0$ and $ax^2+6xy+5y^2+2x+3y+8=0$ intersect at four concyclic points then the value of a is????

The options are:

a) 4

b) -4

c) 6

d) -6

I've tried to eliminate $ax^2$ and then proceed, but could not solve any further.
I also asked my teacher for help, and he said to try and assume the four co-ordinates and use the equation of the circle that is formed. I don't understand what he meant and now he's unavailable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eliminate $xy$ from your equations instead.

Comment: After eliminating the xy terms in both equations, we obtain the expression $ax^2-4y^2-x-3y-1=0$. Does this give the equation of the circle passing through the four points of intersection? if so, then the answer seems to be b) -4.

Comment: Thanks, got it, then a=-4 is the answer.

Comment: Yes, the four points that satisfy both the first two equations also satisfy this one.